# How to order Firebase documents list flutter

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

hope u r good, nice hollidays.

I have an flutterflow app, so i want to show a list of travels ordered by distance, i have a custom action for that, but when I tryt to order that list, always get the unordered list, is like `listRequest` and `orderedListRequest` have the same values.

Thanks in advance.

sry for my bad eng.

```
import 'packagutter/foundation.dart';

import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import 'index.dart'; // Imports other custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom action code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'dart:math';

Future<List<TravelsRecord>?> driverDistance(
  LatLng? driverLocation,
  List<TravelsRecord>? listRequest,
) async {
  // Add your function code here!

  List<TravelsRecord> orderedListRequest = [];
  List distances = [];

  double deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * (pi / 180);
  }

  double getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
    var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1); // deg2rad below
    var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
    var a = sin(dLat / 2) * sin(dLat / 2) +
        cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * sin(dLon / 2) * sin(dLon / 2);
    var c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c; // Distance in km
    return d;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < listRequest!.length; i++) {
    double distance = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(
        driverLocation!.latitude,
        driverLocation.longitude,
        listRequest[i].snapshotData['other_coordinate'].latitude,
        listRequest[i].snapshotData['other_coordinate'].longitude);
    distances.add({'distance': distance, 'index': i});
  }
  distances.sort((a, b) => a['distance'].compareTo(b['distance']));

  for (var i = 0; i < distances.length; i++) {
    orderedListRequest.add(listRequest[distances[i]['index']]);
  }
  
  return orderedListRequest;
}
```

I made a complete debug of the app and the list appears to be ordered, but in  front is unordered,

I tried to separate the index from the distance.

Comment: Since you're using FlutterFlow, make sure that the widget or component that displays the TravelsRecord list is updated to reflect the changes. Sometimes, the issue might be with the UI not updating rather than the sorting logic itself.